# Layered Java JPanels

Tags: java, swing

I have overlayed JPanels, background has an image that prevents foreground from painting on applet's load. 
setOpaque(false) works fine (repaints both panels twenty times thou[?]), but I need it opaque to have BG color, opaque background causes repainting itself 3 times, and that wipes out the top panel:

```
public class LayeredPanelsTest extends JApplet
{
private Image _image;

@Override
public void init()
{
    _image = getImage( getDocumentBase(), "./images/flag.GIF" );
    setSize( 450, 450 );
    setLayout( new OverlayLayout( getContentPane() ) );

    final BottomPanel background = new BottomPanel();
    background.setBounds( 10, 10, 400, 400 );

    final TopPanel foreGround = new TopPanel();
    foreGround.setBounds( 10, 10, 400, 400 );

    add( foreGround );
    add( background );
}

public class BottomPanel extends JPanel
{
    public BottomPanel()
    {
        setBackground(Color.CYAN);
        setLayout( new FlowLayout() );
        setOpaque( true );//with false foreground is painted just fine, but they get repainted like 20 times.
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent( final Graphics g )
    {
        super.paintComponent( g );
        g.drawImage( _image, 10, 10, this );
        System.out.println( "Bottom" );
    }
}

public class TopPanel extends JPanel
{
    int _mouseX = 10;

    public TopPanel()
    {
        setLayout( new FlowLayout() );
        setOpaque( false );

        addMouseListener( new MouseAdapter()
        {
            @Override
            public void mousePressed( final MouseEvent evt ) {
                _mouseX = evt.getX();
                repaint();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent( final Graphics g )
    {
        super.paintComponent( g );
        g.drawLine( _mouseX, 0, _mouseX, 80);
        System.out.println( "Top" );
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Looks like MediaTracker's waitForID(0) solved it. Testing it now.

Comment: Let's start with [Java Plugin support deprecated](http://www.gizmodo.com.au/2016/01/rest-in-hell-java-plug-in/) and [Moving to a Plugin-Free Web](https://blogs.oracle.com/java-platform-group/entry/moving_to_a_plugin_free) and move onto [Reading/Loading an Image](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) and not to mention [How to Use Labels](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/label.html) for displaying images

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify

Comment: Interesting historical Java's development from "The most secure technology!" to "Scrap Java applet first, then switch to other issues!"

Comment: Thank you for the good points, and pointers!
1) Verified, waitForID() did solve the problem.
2) Although solutions like "using Benjamin Moore paint to improve the sound of your stereo" is strange, I'll take a look at the Labels, who knows, maybe they handle MP3's too.
3) Not sure I understood null layout suggestion, I didn't use nulls in this case. Nor I have a use for layout when I draw all the components and I don't re-size any JComponents.

Comment: I think the decision to move away from applets is multi levelled decision, apart from the security issues, html5 can now basically do pretty much what applets could and the push by the browser developers to abandon some plugins (looking at you flash)

Comment: The suggestion of using a label is the difference between buying a stereo and try to build your own (with redumentry electronics knowledge). Since you're using setBounds, I assume you're using a null layout, since there is really no other reason to use it

Comment: I hoped that RSA certificates would keep applets alive, but looks like they are dead no matter the signing, right?  

My "flash" is really complicated, hundreds of classes and interfaces, moving it to a different technology would be a huge project. Having it as a downloadable app is quite an annoyance.